# Does any know what the translation is?

Tags: translation

I found this in my moms stuff that she gave me a long time ago, help?
[image]

Comment: FYI, this is Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

勇

- brave
- bold
- adventurous
- daring
- courageous
- firm
- undaunted

Answer (score 1):

It is 勇(brave; courage),  as in 勇敢(brave)，勇气(courage)